# Adding an arbitrary number of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let say I have below 2 `pandas dataframes`

```
import pandas as pd
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1999, -11234], 'B' : [88888, -345], 'C' : [-7777, -8978], 'D' : [7777, -8978]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [999, 1234], 'B' : [8888, -345], 'C' : [-7777, -8978]})
Collection = [dat1, dat2]
```

In my original case, I actually have an arbitrary number of dataframes in the list `Collection`. Now I want to add all such dataframes with element-by-element addition, based on row and column matches (if in a dataframe, if a column and/or row is missing then corresponding value will be assumed as 0 in such addition).

Is there any direct method/function available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all the dataframes together, then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `sum` to get your desired result:

```py
import pandas as pd

dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1999, -11234], 'B': [88888, -345], 'C': [-7777, -8978], 'D': [7777, -8978]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [999, 1234], 'B': [8888, -345], 'C': [-7777, -8978]})
dat3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 200], 'B': [300, -400], 'C': [500, 600], 'D': [700, 800]})
collection = [dat1, dat2, dat3]

pd.concat(collection).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
      A      B      C       D
0  3098  98076 -15054  8477.0
1 -9800  -1090 -17356 -8178.0
```

Thanks to @SashSinha for the data

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) along with [`pd.DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas-dataframe-add) to add an arbitrary number of dataframes together:

```py
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1999, -11234], 'B': [88888, -345], 'C': [-7777, -8978], 'D': [7777, -8978]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [999, 1234], 'B': [8888, -345], 'C': [-7777, -8978]})
dat3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 200], 'B': [300, -400], 'C': [500, 600], 'D': [700, 800]})
collection = [dat1, dat2, dat3]
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), collection)
```

This will sum the DataFrames in the `collection` list, filling any missing values with 0.

**Output `result`:**

| index | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3098 | 98076 | -15054 | 8477.0 |
| 1 | -9800 | -1090 | -17356 | -8178.0 |